# Unrecognized escape sequence when try to replace empty string

Tags: c#, regex

```
string serverPath = Regex.Replace(mytext, "\Api", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

mytext=D:\Trunck\Api\web\Resources\images\event-images\e1ae04a2-e63f-4831-a5ee-2f0d2713f8a2.png
```

How can I replace `\api` with empty string or I need a final `mytext` as `D:\Trunck\web\Resources\images\event-images\e1ae04a2-e63f-4831-a5ee-2f0d2713f8a2.png`

When I use above regex, it says `Unrecognized escape sequence`.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `\` is the escape character in C#, you need to escape it as well. You also need to escape the backslash, since it has a special meaning in regex too.

```
"\\\\Api"
```

(so 'escape in C#' backslash, 'escape in regex' backslash...)

Or use a string literal:

```
@"\\Api"
```